# SQL Server Data Tools 2012 - deployment package for multiple databases

Tags: sql-server, svn, continuous-integration, sql-server-2012-datatools

In our company we have database solution that contains three SQL Server instances each with different databases. Each instance has some jobs and replication.
As for now we are maintaining creation and update scripts manually and execute them with bat files.
Our deployment package contains scripts for all objects including jobs and replication.

We want to automate our process to make and test deployment packages after every svn commit - continuous integration. Also we have branches for every release. Release correspond to a database version. Different clients have different releases/versions installed. We need to create deployment package for any branch.

Can we use SQL Server Data Tools 2012 for our needs? I have only seen tutorials for single database and I don't know how to use it in more complex environment.

Optionally we could use Data Tools for maintaining schema scripts and write manually scripts for jobs/replication. But can we use the build process to combine it all into one package?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use SSDT for this, by way of [Publish Profiles](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2012/05/09/publish-profile-files-in-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt.aspx). Create a publish profile for each instance and set up your CI jobs accordingly.

Standardizing your database names across instances (especially if they're all for the same product) would help.

Comment: I think I should create a solution for each instance, then create a project for each db. Next to create Publish Profiles for each db and incorporate them in a script to execute in sequence. But Data Tools imported only database objects. I need also scripts for database itself as well as jobs and replication. How to do it?